# Weird issue copying files to a samba share

Tags: samba

Weird issue copying files to a samba share

I'm having this weird issue where I connect to a samba share (my home directory) in my Linux server from a windows client, when I try to copy some files, some of them success, others fail with access denied message, even when it's the same directory.

It doesn't seems to be a file name issue (tried renaming to something with a couple of alphabetic characters) nor a size issue, some bigger files are copied without problem.

It seems for some reason it assumes some files already exist there (they don't) because I'm asked if I want to overwrite, if I accept the file is written empty and the access denied message pops up.

Can this be some kind of cache issue? I can see a pattern where the files that fail were already in that disk (under a different directory tho).

Comment: Your Samba share must have at least the following settings for permissions for correct operation in Windows:  `create mask = 0660` _(new files created will be given `0660` permissions for the Samba user creating them)_ & `directory mask = 0750` _(new directories created will be given `0750` permissions for the Samba user creating them)_.  The share's directory must be owned by either the Samba user or a group the Samba user is apart of _(if the latter, directory permissions must be `0770`)_ and file/directory permissions must be `660`/`750`||`770`.

Comment: @JW0914 please note I explained some files copy just fine.

Comment: Do you have all the above set?  If so, check the Samba server's log file to determine what's going on.

Comment: Nothing relevant at /var/log/samba/ 
log.client_ip is empty.

Comment: @JW0914 and yes, I have tried different masks, from 0 to 0777, makes no difference.

Comment: Review the `smb.conf` & increase the log [verbosity](https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch04_08.html), restart the Samba server, `tail -f` the log, & perform the accessed denied action on Windows, reviewing the log output. It's likely either wrong masks _(files must be **at least** `660` [don't set files to `7` for any UGO] & directories must be **at least** `750`)_, wrong ownership/UGO permissions on the server, or a setting in `smb.conf` (there may be certain [parameter values](https://www.ixsystems.com/documentation/freenas/11.2/sharing.html#avail-vfs-modules-tab) that must be set)

Comment: I increased log verbosity to maximum, no errors except this one "cannot get attributes from ea on file Series" it doesn't seems to be the cause, I added "store dos attrributes = no" to the .conf, restarted, tried copying again and the error disappeared, the problem still persists. Now, "Series" is the directory I'm trying to copy to, why is it mentioned as a file?

Comment: I don't have a clue then... every time I've encountered this, from OpenWrt to FreeNAS, it's always been down to the things in my last comment.  It may be worth posting in the forum for whatever distro you're using as well. _(The parameter value list link in my prior comment is for FreeNAS, but the majority of those aren't FreeNAS/ZFS specific; it's easier to link to a cohesive list than tell someone to comb through the relevant Samba man pages.)_

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue here. I've cross-validated this issue and found out that if I used other samba-client software like ones in Android, there won't be any problems in copying or replacing files; also if I used another Windows computer and launch Windows Explorer to copying files, there won't be any problems in copying or replacing files.

It's very weird, and I still cannot locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same issue here.
While error message unclear, in my case Windows' Attachment Manager's policy was a cause.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/information-about-the-attachment-manager-in-microsoft-windows-c48a4dcd-8de5-2af5-ee9b-cd795ae42738

I resolved it after 'unblocking' a file with admin rights by

RMB on file -> Properties -> General Tab -> Security section -> Click on Unblock checkbox